# Where to store websocket sessions on JavaEE REST application

Tags: rest, websocket, java-ee-7

I am working with websockets in order to notify one or several clients when an event occurs. 
As this project is following the REST approach (JavaEE, wildfly10), I am not sure where to store the websocket sessions, there is no Session (or similar) object, and the basic sample implements a singleton queue, but I think this is not a good option. 
I was thinking to use a Singleton session bean, but as I know, in a clustered environment, every node has it's own instance.
I know REST is about no states in server, but my manager asked to do this with websockets.
Maybe Infinispan (integrated in wildFly) is a good option (I am trying that), but ¿is there another option?